Entropy of mixing via partial pressures
I was deriving the equations for calculating the entropy change $\Delta S_M$ of the system where ideal gases are being mixed.
The first one utilizes partial pressures via Dalton's law:
$$\Delta S_M= \sum_{i}^{N}n_i\left(C_{mp}\space ln\frac{T_M}{T_i}-R\space ln\frac{p'_i}{p_i}\right)\tag1$$
The second equation utilizes only final values of the pressure of the mix, $p_M$:
$$\Delta S_M= \sum_{i}^{N}n_i\left(C_{mp}\space ln\frac{T_M}{T_i}-R\space ln\frac{p_M}{p_i}\right)-R\space n_M\sum_{i}^{N}y_i\space ln(y_i)\tag2$$
Why does the utilization of partial pressures in equation $(1)$ take in account the entropy change that happens purely from mixing two different gases (the last term in equation $(2)$) and we don't have to write it out explicitly as we had in equation $(2)$?

Because, in eon 1, the gases are issued to be pure in their initial state, and $p_i$ represents the pressure of the pure species initially.
